# In JS, what is filtered data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am new to JS and jQuery and during some learning about jQuery UI Autocomplete API, I came across this paragraph:

> A response callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. **This data should be filtered based on the provided term**, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data.

So, what is filtered data? Is it simply an object with key-value pairs?

Thank you very much.

Comment: That's for autocomplete, not accordoon.

Comment: Oops. I edited the questions. Thank you. :)

Comment: It's days that's been filtered according to some criteria, like "starts with" or "contains".

Comment: `can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data`

Comment: I'm sorry, I do not thinks I understand the answer. Is this sentence talking about the server-side or it regards the js should be written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Intuitive Explanation (Less Formal)

`2,medium,1,easy,3,  hard`

This data is hard to read and find out what is going on here. Whenever we have data, in order to make any meaning of it, we usually have to make it malleable to mathematical manipulation (Put it in a form that allows you to easily do math on it).

We know that `2` probably matches with `medium` and `1` matches with `easy` but it is very hard to make use of it both visually and analytically.

#### Complexity Scale:

Easy| Medium | Hard

--- |         --- |        ---

1 |          2 |          3

Hopefully, you will agree that the data set in a tabulated form is easer to read, visualize, and perform computations on. A person who is a data analyst, usually spends 70-80% of their job simply *cleaning* the data.

In your case your data simply needs to be filtered. Filter can mean many things like at times you might have to jQuery each function and parse it as a JSON. Which you might need to iterate and filter, later.

To answer your question in further depth, please provide a little bit more detail.

Comment: Wow. Awsome answer. Well, in my code there is an array with an object in it that it sent to the response callback function, and i was wondering if that is the way to filter the data, but using an object with key-value pairs. I hope I am making any sence lol.

Comment: If you could provide the code, that would be helpful! Using an object would not necessarily be **filtering** the data. It could be a way of filtering your data a lot easier!

If my answer helped, please check the tick mark!

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/NyG48Yb9). The array is `resp`. Thank you very much. Also, can you please add a positive point to the question? I do not know why someone marked it as unclear or unuseful.

Comment: Yup I did that. It's a little unclear and you should show more research for your work generally but it is understandable as you are just starting out in Web development. I thought it was decent though for the record.

Comment: Yes in this case you would be finding key value pairs and pulling out the needed information from the values of the keys. This code was relevant to answering the question. I don't think you would get a down vote  if you had that in there. Remember, the more information you put in your question, the better!